# Why do local network hostnames resolve only in certain cases? 

Tags: snow-leopard, dns

I have a linksys router which runs "tomato" Linux and serves as the local DNS server. It runs dnsmasq.

I recently upgraded from OS X 10.4 to 10.6. Since then, resolution of hostnames on my local network works in some cases but not others. Previously, this all worked as expected.

Here's an example:

```
tesla:~ cell$ ping watt
ping: cannot resolve watt: Unknown host

tesla:~ cell$ ping watt.local
ping: cannot resolve watt.local: Unknown host

tesla:~ cell$ ping -c1 192.168.42.1
PING 192.168.42.1 (192.168.42.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.659 ms

--- 192.168.42.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.659/0.659/0.659/0.000 ms

tesla:~ cell$ host watt.local
watt.local has address 192.168.42.1

tesla:~ cell$ host watt
watt.local has address 192.168.42.1
```

My guess is that the `host` command is querying the DNS server directly, whereas `ping` and any GUI apps (ie. Safari) are using some sort of Mac DNS resolution routines, which are not working properly.

Please let me know if there's any other info I should provide.

Edit: included pinging ip directly in above example

Edit 2: My domain is using .local

Comment: ZOMG!!!  "By default, any hostname ending in .local is treated as a Bonjour host rather than by querying the DNS server entries in Network preferences."  ARGH!!! why couldn't they have picked something like ".bonjour"?  see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2385?viewlocale=en_US

Comment: ugh, you can't simply disable bonjour because of http://tech.karbassi.com/2007/11/06/leopard-turn-off-bonjour-mdnsresponder/

Comment: does pinging the IP directly work?

Comment: indeed, changing your domain name appears to be the path of least resistance.  I'm surprised -- apple typically makes very smart decisions in how they choose to implement things.  this is the first implementation decision I've come across which I'd really consider to be quite a boner.  I mean seriously, picking ANYTHING other than ".local" to special-case for bonjour would have been better.

Comment: @Kyle yes, it does.  I should have thought to mention that.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're serving .local via unicast DNS (instead of multicast DNS, as specified in [this draft internet standard](http://files.multicastdns.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-multicastdns.txt)), include an SOA record for .local; as of v10.6, OS X detects this and switches .local resolution to unicast DNS.  Earlier versions of OS X have other methods of forcing unicast resolution - see Apple's [KB article #HT3473](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473) for details.

Answer (score -1):

solution: don't use '.local' as your domain name.  lame.